# How to increase the left padding on a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

The 0 padding on the left side is pretty distracting. Is there a script to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Old [DOS Prompt](http://www.chami.com/tips/windows/020497W.html) command still work. Type in you command prompt window:

```
prompt $p$g
```

with however many spaces *after* $p$g you want padding to be.
This will last for the duration of the command prompt session. To make it stick edit/add PROMPT to your environmental variables:

[image: PROMPT Variable]

Comment: hmm looks good. however it doesn't add padding to standard output as well. do you happen to know how to do that as well?